# View models vs custom dicts when returning data in a python web app?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a relatively new python user, coming from the .NET world.

I'm working on a web application with a python backend (using Flask and SQLAlchemy), where the db models are defined using SQLAlchemy and now I'm writing my first function where I want to retrieve data from the database and bring to the frontend.

Here is a *non-functional* example (since SQLAlchemy cannot be jsonified directly) just to show what I want to do:

```
@app.route('/validationrules', methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def getValidationRules():

    return jsonify(db.session.query(ValidationRules).all())
```

My question is, is it customary to create view models when using the stack I mentioned above, and use those to create a bridge between the SQLAlchemy and json?  Or do I just create a custom dict in every method and jsonify that?

Some search results also suggested that I create a base model with a to_dict method, and have all my database models inherit from that, but that seems a bit too coupled to me.

What are the best practices for a case like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549437/4711754) answer I would now change my answer to use marshmallow / marshmallow-sqlalchemy.

**Previous answer:**

I don't know the answer for certain but...

From Miguel Grinberg's Flask Web Development 2nd edition, page 210-213 the approach he uses is to have a method

```
def Post(db.Model):
    # ...
    def to_json(self):
        json_post = {
            ** json using model **
        }
        return json_post
```

defined in the **models.py**

Comment: Take a look at Chapter 14 API(4a) https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/commits/master

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting.  This to_json method is much nicer than the to_dict method I saw e.g. [here](https://riptutorial.com/sqlalchemy/example/6614/converting-a-query-result-to-dict) because this does not couple together the members of the model and the "view model" automatically.  In the example you provided, every model just has their own definition of a view model.  Seems good to me!

Comment: Please note my update changes how I would now approach this

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.