# Mocking session.add and returning primary key which would have been generated by Database table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mocking

i am trying to mock sqlalchemy session.add such that when i insert session.add(order) and commit it , it should give me order.orderId back which i will use to extends the test case further .

```
   session.add(order)
        session.commit()
        return order.orderId
```

i have mocked sessionMaker  i.e `mocker.patch.object(file_name, "create_pgdb_engine")` which return me mock but i am getting error like

Instance  has a NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such as within a order() event.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to mock lower level database components to create mock objects is probably not a very good strategy for testing. If you're trying to mock sqlalchemy objects for unit testing purposes, look into [Factory-boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). Check out the [full example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534149/how-do-i-produce-nested-json-from-database-query-with-joins-using-python-sqla/55549437#55549437) of how a test framework can be constructed using sqlalchemy and factory-boy.

Comment: Thanks..i will refer it for sure ...for now i mocked the method call which  returned me orderid with some specific value rather than trying to mock  in depth as  you have already suggested.