# Mocking a Sqlalchemy session for pytest

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I don't know if this can be done but I'm trying to mock my db.session.save.

I'm using flask and flask-alchemy.

db.py

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

The unit test

```py
def test_post(self):
    with app.app_context():
        with app.test_client() as client:
            with mock.patch('models.db.session.save') as mock_save:
                with mock.patch('models.db.session.commit') as mock_commit:

                    data = self.gen_legend_data()
                    response = client.post('/legends', data=json.dumps([data]), headers=access_header)

                    assert response.status_code == 200
                    mock_save.assert_called()
                    mock_commit.assert_called_once()
```

And the method:

```py
def post(cls):
    legends = schemas.Legends(many=True).load(request.get_json())

    for legend in legends:
        db.session.add(legend)

    db.session.commit()

    return {'message': 'legends saved'}, 200
```

I'm trying to mock the db.session.add and db.session.commit. I've tried `db.session.save` and `legends.models.db.session.save` and `models.db.session.save`. They all came back with the save error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models.db.session'; 'models.db' is not a package
```

I don't get the error and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Or am I doing something that is totally wrong in wanting to mock a db.session?

Thanks.
Desmond

Comment: Why would you mock `Session.save()`, when there are no calls to such method in your code? (And `Session` does not have such a method)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem you're running into here is better served by restructuring your code so that it's more testable rather than mocking out every component, or otherwise making a (very) slow integration test. If you get in the habit of writing tests in that way, then over time you'll end up with a slow build that will take too long to run, and you'll end up with fragile tests (good talk on the subject of why fast tests are important [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAxiiRPHS9k)).

Let's take a look at this route:

```py
def post(cls):
    legends = schemas.Legends(many=True).load(request.get_json())

    for legend in legends:
        db.session.add(legend)

    db.session.commit()

    return {'message': 'legends saved'}, 200
```

...and decompose it:

```py
import typing
from flask import jsonify

class LegendsPostService:

    def __init__(self, json_args, _session=None) -> None:
        self.json_args = json_args
        self.session = _session or db.session

    def _get_legends(self) -> Legend:
        return schemas.Legends(many=True).load(self.json_args)

    def post(self) -> typing.List[typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]]:
        legends = self._get_legends()

        for legend in legends:
            self.session.add(legend)

        self.session.commit()
        return schemas.Legends(many=True).dump(legends)

def post(cls):
    service = LegendsPostService(json_args=request.get_json())
    service.post()
    return jsonify({'message': 'legends saved'})
```

Notice how we've isolated nearly all the points of failure from `post` into `LegendsPostService`, and further, we've removed all the flask internals from it as well (no global request objects floating around, etc). We've even given it the ability to mock out `session` if we need to for testing later on.

I would recommend you focus your testing efforts on writing test cases for `LegendsPostService`. Once you've got excellent tests for `LegendsPostService`, decide if you believe that even *more* test coverage will add value. If you do, *then* consider writing one simple integration test for `post()` to tie it all together.

The next thing you need to consider is how you want to think about SQLAlchemy objects in tests. I recommend just using FactoryBoy for auto-creating "mock" models for you. Here's a full application example for how to setup flask / sqlalchemy / factory-boy in this way: [How do I produce nested JSON from database query with joins? Using Python / SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534149/how-do-i-produce-nested-json-from-database-query-with-joins-using-python-sqla/55549437#55549437)

Here's how I'd write a test for `LegendsPostService` (apologies as this is a bit hasty and doesn't perfectly represent what you're trying to do - but you should be able to adjust these tests for your use case):

```py
from factory.alchemy import SQLAlchemyModelFactory

class ModelFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session

# setup your factory for Legends:
class LegendsFactory(ModelFactory):
    logo_url = factory.Faker('image_url')
    class Meta(ModelFactory.Meta):
        model = Legends


from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch


# neither of these tests even need a database connection!
# so you should be able to write HUNDREDS of similar tests
# and you should be able to run hundreds of them in seconds (not minutes)

def test_LegendsPostService_can_init():
    session = MagicMock()
    service = LegendsPostService(json_args={'foo': 'bar'}, _session=session)
    assert service.session is session
    assert service.json_args['foo'] == 'bar'


def test_LegendsPostService_can_post():
    session = MagicMock()
    service = LegendsPostService(json_args={'foo': 'bar'}, _session=session)

    # let's make some fake Legends for our service!
    legends = LegendsFactory.build_batch(2)

    with patch.object(service, '_get_legends') as _get_legends:
        _get_legends.return_value = legends
        legends_post_json = service.post()

    # look, Ma! No database connection!
    assert legends_post_json[0]['image_url'] == legends[0].image_url
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Stephen. That helped a lot. Just a question, the line session = MagicMock() is mocking the db.session, correctly. So when the codes get to the self.session.add(), it will just use the MagicMock() object and not call the actual session.

Comment: Yes, that's accurate. When you mock `session`, you are writing a unit test and not a system / integrated test. If you feel the need to have an integrated test to make sure all the sqlalchemy / database behavioral interactions are working as expected, you can write an integration test for that.

Comment: I recommend writing as few integrated tests as possible (i.e. ones that don't mock sqlalchemy & talk to the database). Why? Several reasons, but one of the more subtle reasons is one that you might not notice until a couple years into your project.. Consider that running 1000 unit tests should take less than 30 seconds. running 1000 integration tests, however, may take 30mins+